# Как правильно: "по истечению обстоятельств" или "по стечению обстоятельств"?

Tags: общие-вопросы, история, фразеология

Как-то дошли до спора с подругой. "Её победа была глупым *истечением обстоятельств*." Я сказала, что, наверное, уместнее было бы "её победа была глупым *стечением обстоятельств*." Она мне не поверила. Сказала, что позвонила своему репетитору, которая является профессором филологических наук, а та ей пояснила, что, цитирую:
*Стечение обстоятельств* - это тогда, когда события произошли с небольшим сроком давности, не больше суток. 
*Истечение обстоятельств* - это тогда, когда события произошли с давностью больше суток. "

Все равно мне кажется, что это не так. Ведь это же фразеологизм - *стечение обстоятельств*, то есть случайность. Но она сказала, что это еще одно полтверждение ее правоты, ведь это было запланированное действие, совсем не случайное. Пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

**Стечение обстоятельств** - правильная фраза (*истечение* таковых - стилистическая ошибка). "**Истекать**" может то, что измеряется количеством времени (для промежутка которого "заканчиваться" и "истекать" - синонимы), например, условленные **сроки**. В данном же случае под *стечением обстоятельств* понимается *соединение причин*: в один и тот же момент времени в одном и том же месте оказались вместе несколько факторов, как бы "стеклись воедино" и стали общей причиной той самой победы. Саму победу называть "стечением обстоятельств" не совсем точно (хотя в разговоре для упрощения так сказать можно), поскольку это, скорее, совокупная причина победы. Лучше сказать, что **победа обусловлена (объясняется) глупым стечением обстоятельств** (Аннушка пролила масло, главный соперник опоздал, поскользнулся и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "По истечении обстоятельств" некорректно. Обратимся к словарям.

Истечение, 2. Окончание какого-л. срока, приход к концу (о времени). Т.е. истечь может срок, время.

По истечении чего, в знач. предлога с род. (книжн.) после того, как миновало какое-н. время, по прошествии времени. Заказ аннулирован по истечении месяца.

> **ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВО**, -а; ср. 1. ***Событие, факт, сопутствующие чему-л., связанные с чем-л.; та или иная сторона дела, события***. Существенное о.  Это о. нам не помешает. Знакомство происходило при особых обстоятельствах. Приоткрыть некоторые обстоятельства загадочной гибели судна. 2. мн. ***Совокупность условий, в которых что-л. происходит, определяющих положение кого-, чего-л.*** Трудные обстоятельства. Отличные обстоятельства. Воспользоваться обстоятельствами. Обстоятельства вынуждают меня уехать. Ваши обстоятельства нам известны. Поступайте по обстоятельствам! (в зависимости от условий). ***Счастливое (несчастливое) стечение обстоятельств (совокупность условий, обстановка в определённый момент).*** Не ссылайтесь на обстоятельства! (не оправдывайте свои поступки, поведение определёнными условиями).

Как видите из значении этих слов, "обстоятельства" истечь не могут .